# How do I define a method in an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I go about defining a method, e.g. `void doSuff()` in an anonymous type?  All documentation I can find uses only anonymous restricted basically to property lists.  Can I even define a method in an anonymous type?

EDIT:  OK, a quick look at very quick answers tells me this is impossible.  Is there any way at all to construct a type dynamically and add an anonymous method to a delegate property on that type?  I'm looking for a C# way to accomplish what the following JavaScript does:

```
...
person.getCreditLimit = function() { ... }
...
```

Comment: Lots of different answers for this one, apparently. Some say you can, some say you can't. Please accept the correct answer in your case. Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely can, with delegates:

```
Action action = MethoThatDoesSomething;
var obj = new
          {
              DoSomething = action
          };

obj.DoSomething();
```

I tried with a lambda in the `new { ... }` and that didn't work, but the above is totally fine.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can. With delegates you just treat methods as data:

```
var myMethods = from x in new[] { "test" }
                select new { DoStuff = new Func<string>(() => x) };

var method = myMethods.First();
var text = method.DoStuff();
```

What do you think the value of "text" is?

With the Action<> and Func<> generic types you can put (almost) whatever you want in there.
Almost, because you cannot for instance access other properties on the anonymous type, like this:

```
var myMethods = from x in new[] { "test" }
                select new { Text = x, DoStuff = new Func<string>(() => Text) };
```

Comment: Can this method close over fields in the anonymous type? I rather doubt it, but nested anonymous functions might be exploited to simulated this (after all, this is how functional languages implement classes).

Comment: Very good idea! Just a note that the methods will effectively be static though.

Comment: @konrad, I think it might be possible, im gonna try it!

Comment: You mean if the method can do stuff with the other properties on the anonymous type? I doubt so too...

Comment: @leppie, awaiting your results :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, @leppie I do not think that C# has a way for the nested function to get a reference to the anonymous class it is in. Since anonymous class objects are immutable, you would not be able to update property values or anything. What you *could* do, though, is compose your anonymous type completely of a set of functions which share a reference to variables via a closure. But the only data you could expose as properties should be kept immutable. Basically, python’s `self` and JavaScript’s `this` behavior do not exist in C# AFAIK. Interesting concept, though.

Answer (score 3):

You cant, at least not up to .NET 3.5.

Comment: And to clarify for the OP: you can't do *anything* to an anonymous type; no interfaces, no base class, no methods, no attributes, no nothing. Except the properties etc that the compiler provides.

Comment: There's nothing planned for C# 4.0, and I doubt we will ever see this (I can't even imagine how you'd define a method on an anonymous type, some weird Extension Method construction?). But, to be fair, the C# design team is much much smarter and intuitive than me ;)

Comment: Why does that "suck"? If you want classes with more features, declare it yourself...

Comment: @Marc, it does not really suck that badly - I was being overly expressive, but if a type (i.e. precedented by named types) can have method members, then I would expect an apparent, except for naming, equivalent of a type, i.e. the anonymous type, to have method members.

Comment: Surely whatever allows a `dynamic` type to receive a group of method members from an untyped source object could be applied to anonymous types?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
        var anonType = new
        {
            FirstName = "James",
            LastName = "Bond",
            FullName = new Action<string, string>(
                (x, y) =>
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine(x + y );
                    })                
        };

        anonType.FullName("Roger","Moore");
```

Basically using a Lambda for the delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But here is what you could try:

```
var test = new { Foo = new Func<string>(() => "hello") };
test.Foo.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Anonymouse types only contain properties with public get modifiers and overrides of the GetHashCode(), Equals() and ToString().

```
var myclass = new { Name = "Andy", Location = "Bellingham", Sector = 0, };
```

From reflector:

```
[CompilerGenerated, DebuggerDisplay(@"\{ Name = {Name}, Location = {Location}, Sector = {Sector} }", Type="<Anonymous Type>")]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<Name>j__TPar, <Location>j__TPar, <Sector>j__TPar>
{
    // Fields
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Location>j__TPar <Location>i__Field;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Name>j__TPar <Name>i__Field;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Sector>j__TPar <Sector>i__Field;

    // Methods
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <>f__AnonymousType0(<Name>j__TPar Name, <Location>j__TPar Location, <Sector>j__TPar Sector)
    {
        this.<Name>i__Field = Name;
        this.<Location>i__Field = Location;
        this.<Sector>i__Field = Sector;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override bool Equals(object value)
    {
        var type = value as <>f__AnonymousType0<<Name>j__TPar, <Location>j__TPar, <Sector>j__TPar>;
        return ((((type != null) && EqualityComparer<<Name>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<Name>i__Field, type.<Name>i__Field)) && EqualityComparer<<Location>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<Location>i__Field, type.<Location>i__Field)) && EqualityComparer<<Sector>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<Sector>i__Field, type.<Sector>i__Field));
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int num = 0x5fabc4ba;
        num = (-1521134295 * num) + EqualityComparer<<Name>j__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(this.<Name>i__Field);
        num = (-1521134295 * num) + EqualityComparer<<Location>j__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(this.<Location>i__Field);
        return ((-1521134295 * num) + EqualityComparer<<Sector>j__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(this.<Sector>i__Field));
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("{ Name = ");
        builder.Append(this.<Name>i__Field);
        builder.Append(", Location = ");
        builder.Append(this.<Location>i__Field);
        builder.Append(", Sector = ");
        builder.Append(this.<Sector>i__Field);
        builder.Append(" }");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    // Properties
    public <Location>j__TPar Location
    {
        get
        {
            return this.<Location>i__Field;
        }
    }

    public <Name>j__TPar Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.<Name>i__Field;
        }
    }

    public <Sector>j__TPar Sector
    {
        get
        {
            return this.<Sector>i__Field;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For C#, yes. But the tags include .NET - where this is not always true; VB anonymous types can have set accessors.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
// this line should be in class body, not in method
delegate void MyDelegate(); 
var Obj = new {
    MyDel = new MyDelegate(delegate() { MessageBox.Show("yee-haw"); })
};
Obj.MyDel();
```

If you don't want to declare a delegate type, you can use System.Func<>:

```
var Obj = new {
    MyFunc = new Func<string>( delegate() { return "yee-haw"; })
};
MessageBox.Show(Obj.MyFunc());
```