# Is it possible to attach methods to C# anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

It would be desirable to be able to provide e.g. comparison functions (i.e. with lambdas) for an anonymous type, so that they can be sorted by a set of criteria. Is that possible in C#?

Comment: You seem to ask two slightly different questions: one in the title, and one in the body. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @Evan: I think it's a hybrid of both: he wants to define *methods* for anonymous types in *some way*, which could be with lambda syntax or some other kind of syntax. They're asking the same thing even though they seem to be asking about different topics.

Comment: @Mehrdad See, I interpret it as asking how to specify comparison functions for anonymously typed objects (hence the body), and Billy assumed that he would need to attach a comparator method to those objects to do so (hence the title)

Comment: @Evan: How so? I see only one question. I provided an example where attaching the method might be useful (i.e. allowing comparisons), but it's still one question.

Comment: @Evan: Like Billy said, lambdas for sorting were an example of a potential solution, not the original problem.

Comment: @Mehrdad Until he made that comment, it was unclear. Generally, if someone asks a question and gives 1) a problem and 2) a solution to the problem that may or may not work, he's probably asking about the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I define a method in an anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713561/how-do-i-define-a-method-in-an-anonymous-type)

Comment: You marked strange reply as an answer, the correct one is as in linked post -- it IS possible via little trick, using fields as functors. For the outside world this looks exactly like a regular method.

Comment: @macias: No, that isn't true. C# might use the same sytax but at the CLR level they are very different. (And things expecting something like ICompareable won't work that way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, just make a regular class instead.

Possible related: [Can a C# anonymous class implements an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface)

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to be sure. +1.

Comment: It is, in fact, possible in C# to "provide e.g. comparison functions (i.e. with lambdas) for an anonymous type, so that they can be sorted by a set of criteria." Therefore, "No" is incorrect.

Comment: @Evan: I think you missed the title. It's asking for a solution involving *attaching **methods***, not just any solution that involves delegates/lambdas.

Comment: @Downvoters: You must be Java programmers...OP wants an anonymous type that implements some interface e.g. IComparable, in order to pass the instance to some sort method that takes IComparable as a parameter. In Java it's possible, in C# it's not allowed.

Comment: @Danny: Lol just curious, why? Do you mean because you can have methods in anonymous classes in Java, or something else? :)

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are implicitly convertable to System.Comparison`1:

```
var anons = (new[] {new {a = 3}, new {a = 4}, new {a = 2}}).ToList();
anons.Sort((x, y) => (x.a - y.a));
```

You can also use the LINQ `OrderBy` extension method to sort anonymous types.

```
var anons = new[] {new {a = 3}, new {a = 4}, new {a = 2}};
var sorted = anons.OrderBy(s => s.a);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You must declare the type of the comparison function:

```
var anon = new {comparator = (Func<string, int>) (s => s.Length)};
```

Comment: That's not a method, that's a field. -1

Comment: I fail to see how the storage method affects the function's behavior: whether it is a field or a method is irrelevant. I can still call it.

Comment: Because you can't treat the object as an `IComparable` (or anything else) if it's not an actual method.